# How to setup pytorch DDP with NCCL backend in AWS EC2?

Tags: machine-learning, amazon-ec2, pytorch, distributed-computing

I am trying to run some model training using torch DPP with the NCCL backend. Each node consists of an independent AWS EC2 instance with a single nvidia GPU. I have allowed all IP-v4 inbound and outbound traffic in the nodes' security group.

My python code looks something like this, using pytorch 2.1.0:

```py
model = ... # some nn.Module
device = 'cuda:0' # each node has a single GPU

torch.distributed.init_process_group(
    backend=torch.distributed.Backend.NCCL,
    rank=node_rank,
    world_size=world_size,
    init_method=(f'tcp://{rank_0_ip}:{rank_0_port}')
)

model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(
    model.to(device),
    device_ids=[0],
    output_device=0
)

# perform the training 
...
```

### The issue/question:

This hangs forever upon calling `DistributedDataParallel`. Am I missing something or setting things poorly?

For what it's worth, running on a single node with the same code runs fine so I suspect this is something to do with the interaction between NCCL setup and AWS EC2.

### Extra logs

I have set the `NCCL_DEBUG=INFO` env variable to get more info. On my test setup with 2 nodes I get:

On node with rank 1:

```
ip-172-31-4-255:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO cudaDriverVersion 12020
ip-172-31-4-255:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using ens5:172.31.4.255<0>
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Plugin Path : /opt/hpcx/nccl_rdma_sharp_plugin/lib/libnccl-net.so
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO P2P plugin IBext
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO NET/IB : No device found.
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO NET/IB : No device found.
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Socket : Using [0]ens5:172.31.4.255<0>
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Using network Socket
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Trees [0] -1/-1/-1->1->0 [1] 0/-1/-1->1->-1
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO P2P Chunksize set to 131072
ip-172-31-4-255:1:17 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Socket: Using 2 threads and 8 sockets per thread
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 0[1e0] -> 1[1e0] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
ip-172-31-4-255:1:17 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Socket: Using 2 threads and 8 sockets per thread
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 0[1e0] -> 1[1e0] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 1[1e0] -> 0[1e0] [send] via NET/Socket/0
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 1[1e0] -> 0[1e0] [send] via NET/Socket/0
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Connected all rings
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO Connected all trees
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO threadThresholds 8/8/64 | 16/8/64 | 512 | 512
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO 2 coll channels, 0 nvls channels, 2 p2p channels, 2 p2p channels per peer
ip-172-31-4-255:1:16 [0] NCCL INFO comm 0x55b576f0cd10 rank 1 nranks 2 cudaDev 0 busId 1e0 commId 0x659b86aa3c384f00 - Init COMPLETE
```

On node with rank 0

```
ip-172-31-2-203:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO Bootstrap : Using ens5:172.31.2.203<0>
ip-172-31-2-203:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin: Failed to find ncclNetPlugin_v7 symbol.
ip-172-31-2-203:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin: Loaded net plugin NCCL RDMA Plugin v6 (v6)
ip-172-31-2-203:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin: Failed to find ncclCollNetPlugin_v7 symbol.
ip-172-31-2-203:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Plugin: Loaded coll plugin SHARP (v6)
ip-172-31-2-203:1:1 [0] NCCL INFO cudaDriverVersion 12020
NCCL version 2.19.3+cuda12.2
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Plugin Path : /opt/hpcx/nccl_rdma_sharp_plugin/lib/libnccl-net.so
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO P2P plugin IBext
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO NET/IB : No device found.
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO NET/IB : No device found.
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Socket : Using [0]ens5:172.31.2.203<0>
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Using non-device net plugin version 0
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Using network Socket
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO comm 0x560160aaedf0 rank 0 nranks 2 cudaDev 0 nvmlDev 0 busId 1e0 commId 0x659b86aa3c384f00 - Init START
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/02 :    0   1
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/02 :    0   1
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Trees [0] 1/-1/-1->0->-1 [1] -1/-1/-1->0->1
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO P2P Chunksize set to 131072
ip-172-31-2-203:1:36 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Socket: Using 2 threads and 8 sockets per thread
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 1[1] -> 0[0] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
ip-172-31-2-203:1:36 [0] NCCL INFO NET/Socket: Using 2 threads and 8 sockets per thread
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 1[1] -> 0[0] [receive] via NET/Socket/0
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 00/0 : 0[0] -> 1[1] [send] via NET/Socket/0
ip-172-31-2-203:1:34 [0] NCCL INFO Channel 01/0 : 0[0] -> 1[1] [send] via NET/Socket/0
```